# Xcode Auto Layout issue with constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout, size-classes

I just started learning Auto Layout yesterday and i'm having a hard time understanding these constraints stuff. I thought I was doing auto layout correctly because my storyboard shows no issues with auto layout and constraints. I got all the UIImageViews where I wanted them in all devices. However, when I build,run a simulator in debug area I get...

```
     Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fabb1d689f0 H:[UIImageView:0x7fabb1d68820(70)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fabb1e983c0 UIImageView:0x7fabb1d68820.centerX == UIView:0x7fabb1d654c0.centerX - 265>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fabb1e98460 UIImageView:0x7fabb1d68820.leading == UIView:0x7fabb1d654c0.leadingMargin    - 20>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fabb1e993c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout- Width' H:[UIView:0x7fabb1d654c0(1024)]>"
 )
```

I get the above message in debug area. Also, when the simulator finally loads the UIImageViews are all stretched for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `UIImageViews` in a `Stack View` which will embed the images together, space them out how you want to, and then add the needed auto layout constraints. This is a new nifty feature of iOS 9.

On Google, or the search engine you use, or YouTube, type in "How to use Stack Views", and I am sure your required tutorial will pop up.